# How to randomly display subset of a dataframe into another dataframe every time we print it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df0 which contains 100 entries. Is there a way to generate a subset of dataframe df1 which has 20 entries appearing in random order in comparison to df0 every time we print df1?

Example -

df0 =

|  | calories | duration | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 420 | 50 | Ana |
| 1 | 380 | 40 | Mike |
| : | : | : | : |
| 99 | 390 | 45 | James |

```
print(df1) #first time
```

|  | calories | duration | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 420 | 50 | Ana |
| 1 | 230 | 10 | Joe |
| : | : | : | : |
| 49 | 380 | 42 | Eli |

```
print(df1) #second time
```

|  | calories | duration | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 620 | 36 | Megan |
| 1 | 390 | 45 | James |
| : | : | : | : |
| 49 | 430 | 42 | Rick |

and so on...

number of columns remain same and all of the values that are appearing in df1 subsets are present in df0.

Comment: You need a random sample from df0? `print(df0.sample(20))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.sample(frac=1).head(20)
```

Comment: Why not `df.sample(n=20)`? But it doesn't seem to be what OP is looking for.

Comment: df.sample(n=20) Will also work.